# Confused in the output of the following programme

Tags: c++

```
float b = 1.0f;
int i = b;
int& j = (int&)i;
cout<<j<<endl;
```

o/p =  1

But for the following scenario

```
float b = 1.0f;
int i = b;
int& j = (int&)b;
cout<<j<<endl;
```

O/P = 1065353216

since both are having the same value it shall show the same result ...Can anyone please let me  know whats really happening when i am doing some change in line number 3 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integer `1` and floating-point `1.0f` may be mathematically the same value, but in C++ they have different types, with different representations.

Casting an *lvalue* to a reference is equivalent to `reinterpret_cast`; it says "look at whatever is in this memory location, and interpret those bytes as an `int`".

In the first case, the memory contains an `int`, so interpreting those bytes as an `int` gives expected value.

In the second case, the memory contains a `float`, so you see the bytes (or perhaps just some of them, or perhaps some extra ones too, if `sizeof(int) != sizeof(float)`) that represent the floating-point number, reinterpreted as an integer.

Your computer probably uses 32-bit `int` and 32-bit [IEEE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) `float` representations. The `float` value `1.0f` has a sign bit of zero, an exponent of zero (represented by the 8-bit value 127, or 01111111 in binary), and a mantissa of 1 (represented by the 23-bit value zero), so the 32-bit pattern would look like:

```
00111111 10000000 00000000 00000000
```

When reinterpreted as an integer, this gives the hex value `0x3f800000`, which is 1065353216 in decimal.

Comment: Can you please explain some thing more regarding your lasr paragraph ..I dont know much more about this mantissa stuff .. I am a newbie in c++.

Comment: @vivek: Follow the [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) to the Wikipedia article on IEEE floating point representations, which explains them better than I can.

Answer (score 3):

In the first one, you are doing everything fine. The compiler is able to convert `float b` to `int i`, losing precision, but it's fine. Now, take a look at my debugger window during the execution of your second example:

[image]

Sorry for my Russian IDE interface, the first column is variable name, the second is value, and the third is type.

As you can see, now the float is simply interpreted as int. So the leading `1` bits are interpreted as the integer's bits, which leads to the result you are getting. So basically, you take the float's binary representation (usually it's represented as sign bit, mantissa and exponent), and try to interpret it as an `int`.

Answer (score 2):

In the first case you're initializing `j` correctly and the cast is superfluous. In the second case you're doing it wrong (i.e. to an object of a different type) but the cast shuts the compiler up.

In this second case, what you get is probably the internal representation of `1.0` interpreted as in integer.

Answer (score 1):

Reference doesn't do any memory allocation, it just places an entry into table of local names and their addresses. In first case name 'j' points to the memory previously allocated to int datatype (for variable 'i'), while in second case name 'j' points to memory allocated to float datatype (for variable 'b'). When you use 'j' compiler interprets data at the appropriate address as if it was int, but in fact some float is placed there, that's why you get some "strange" numbers instead of 1

Answer (score 0):

The first one first casts `b` to an `int` before assigning it to `i`. This is the "proper" way, as the compiler will properly convert the value.

The second one does no casting and re-interpret's `b`'s bits as an integer. If you read up on [floating point format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) you can see exactly why you're getting the value you're getting.

Under the covers, all your variables are just collections of bits. How you interpret those bits changes the perceived value they represent. In the first one, you're rearranging the bit pattern to preserve the "perceived" value (of 1). In the second one, you're not rearranging the bit pattern, and so the perceived value is not properly converted.